# Dynamic File Reading

Tags: java, swing, io, nullpointerexception, filereader

I have a piece of code in Java Swing which browses a txt file and then prints the content of the file in a text area. This is the method which does the work. For some reason which I am overlooking most probably, I am getting a null pointer exception every time I am testing the code. Can you please tell me what I have done wrong or maybe provide a link?

```
private void showText() {                
    try{
        //filePathInputField.setText(new File(file.getFile()).getAbsolutePath());
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileInputPathField.getText());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while((sourceText = br.readLine()) != null){
            sourceText += br.readLine();
        }
        sourceTextArea.setText(sourceText);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        showMessage();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Error that i received after changing the code slightly from your suggestions are:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Java\GUI Project Files\Crypto\Audio Specs.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 3) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I have seen them but still i couldnt fix the error. Must be some mistake I made during the coding part. The stack traces are given below. Can you please check and see?

Comment: I don't try to read code or stack traces in comments, instead [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28790208/edit).  *Where is the MCVE?*

Comment: I think the `FileNotFoundException` is rather obvious: the program cannot find the file. Check the path you provided in the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

`getClass().getResource()` is for packaged files (aka resources). If `filePathInputField` contains a path to a file in your filesystem, that call will return null. You can access it using an instance of [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) or [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPath%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29).

Comment: Thank you for the input but I have earlier tried it with File but that gave the same result. So i did a little reading from here and tried URL. Any other ideas why it might be happening?

Comment: earlier i was using this code module in the URL's place:

` sourceTextArea.setText(new File(file.getFile()).getAbsolutePath()); `

Comment: Sorry the earlier code was:

earlier i was using this code module in the URL's place:

` FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(file.getFile()).getAbsolutePath()); `

Comment: In that case, `new FileReader(new File(filePathInputField.getText()))` should work. If it doesn't, give more info (i.e. full stacktrace of your NPE).

Comment: This is the error I am getting from the stacktrace:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Audio Specs.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)

 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)

 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)

 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)

Comment: `Audio Specs.txt` is not an absolute path. See where the `File` points to like this: `System.out.println(new File("Audio Specs.txt").getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: After having changed it to absolute path, I am still getting the same error.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Java\GUI Project Files\Crypto\Audio Specs.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)

Comment: Does that file exists? Can you access it? `File f = new File("D:\\Java\\GUI Project Files\\Crypto\\Audio Specs.txt"); System.out.println(f.exists()); System.out.println(f.isFile()); System.out.println(f.canRead()); System.out.println(f.canWrite());`

Comment: yes i can access it anytime. Its just on a different directory. I dunno why the swing cannot read it.

Comment: the thing is, I am using a Swing file choser to let the user get the file. So, I cannot really edit the path with the '\\'. Any way to go around this?

Comment: Swing has nothing to do with your file reading code. Use the full path in your input field, or (better yet) use a [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) and get the File instance by `getSelectedFile()`.